G-invariants vertical fields of principal bundles are complete
Let $\pi: P\rightarrow M$ be a G-principal bundle with $G$ action $r_g(p)=pg$ and let $X$ be a vertical vector field of $P$, that is $X_p\in\text{ker}(d\pi)_p$ for each $p\in P$, that is also $G$-invariant: $(dr_g)_pX_p=X(pg)$. I want to show that $X$ is complete.
My proof is the following. First, I show that given $p\in P_x=\pi^{-1}(x)$, the flow $\text{Fl}^X_t(p)\in P_x$, for every $t$ in the definition domain of the flow passing through $p$. We have that $\frac{d}{dt}|_s\pi(\text{Fl}^X_t(p))=(d\pi)_{\text{Fl}^X_s(p)}(X(\text{Fl}^X_s(p)))=0$, since $X$ is vertical. Since the flow at $t=0$ is $p$ it follows that $\pi(\text{Fl}^X_t(p))=\pi(p)=x$ for every t in the flow domain.
Now, fix $p_0\in P_x$, then there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $\text{Fl}^X_t(p_0)$ is defined for every $t\in(-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)$. But since $X$ is $G$-invariant, we have that:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}|_s r_g(\text{Fl}^X_t(p_0))=d(r_g)_{\text{Fl}^X_s(p_0)}X(\text{Fl}^X_s(p_0))=X(r_g(\text{Fl}^X_s(p_0)))
$$
for each $t\in (-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)$ and since $r_g(\text{Fl}^X_0(p_0))=p_0g$ it follows that $r_g(\text{Fl}^X_t(p_0))=\text{Fl}^X_t(r_g(p_0))$. But $P_x=p_0G$, that is, $G$ acts transitively on $P_x$. If the flow passing through $p_0$ wasn't complete, let us say defined only in $(a,b)$, then I could take $s\in(a,b)$ such that $|s-b|<\varepsilon_0$. However $\text{Fl}^X_s(p_0g)=\text{Fl}^X_s(p_0)g=p_0$ for some $g\in G$ and this contradicts the fact that the flow passing through $p_0g$ is defined for $t\in(-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)$.
I think it is right, but I'm asking because I saw people asking almost the same question, but with the assumption that $M$ is compact and I don't think it is necessary.
